# In pyhon , is the any function like the function bind_rows() in R

Tags: python, dplyr

In R `dplyr` pacakage `bind_rows()` can combine dataframe which have no same variables,  is the any same/like function in Python?

Comment: Does `pandas.concat` meet your need? Have a look at this link: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/append-concatenate-rows-python-pandas-row-bind/

Comment: In Python? No. In some python library? Maybe, depends on the library you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pd.concat()`,this will help you:

[concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat)